# Preprocess only local #includes into single file?

Tags: visual-c++, preprocessor

I understand VC++ will let you emit C++ source files which are the result of preprocessor operations e.g. macros are expanded and includes "copy-pasted in line".

Is it possible to restrict this simply to embed included files, which are files in my own project rather than standard libraries?

Comment: Long answer : No - the compiler has no way of distinguishing which included files are yours and which belong to standard libraries, SDKs, whatever. They are just included, and there are various search paths to find them - it doesn't know or care who wrote them.

Comment: So I'd have to make a custom tool for this... I'll take any outline how best to do that as an answer if someone wants to suggest it.

Answer (score 2):

From the outside there's no way you can tell from which syntax form (<> or "") the content is being preprocessed. Unless a kind of API was exposed by the preprocessor, which is not the case here.

A not so elegant (and not strictly correct) solution I could propose would be to index a preprocessed version of all Standard headers (there are not that many) and after preprocessing the source of interest you could run a string matching script to detect the known files and remove the corresponding content from the final output.

Notice this is subjected to flaws because the `#include` system is purely textual and influenced by whatever macros are (un)defined at the time of inclusion and order matters. But depending on the complexity of the code you're working on this might give reasonable results.

By the way, may I ask what is the ultimate goal of your task?

**Edit:** Or actually... Maybe it's possible that you filter the sources before-hand to remove the undesired `#include`s and then submit it to preprocessing?

Comment: It's actually quite a specific goal/use-case. For programming contests, I often have to submit a single file with all my code... but working on a single file C++ project gets tricky so I'd rather work in multiple files as normal and then easily package everything together automatically.